# How can I change the context of kubectl commands and helm?

Tags: kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

Currently helm is installing to the wrong cluster on GKE, how can I install to a different cluster?

Comment: What details or clarity does this need? it's self answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the desired cluster is available to you

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

Now you need to reconcile that command (which has the data from Google) with your local kubectl, you can do that with

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

If you do not see a matching context, you can add one. The following command adds the context and sets it as the current-context, which is weird for a command called "get-credentials" but that's Google.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials myCluster --region=us-central1
```

But, if there is already a context in your kubectl that you merely want to switch to you can do that with

```
kubectl config use-context myContext
```

---

For more information see this link

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl